# Add 7 days to PHP date and change format at once

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I have a date being echoed in my code like so.

```
date("F j", strtotime($dateEnd))
```

I want to change it to do something like...

```
date("+7 day", "F j", strtotime($dateEnd))
```

But adding the +7 day stops it from working, but in other situations adding days that way has worked. Is it possible to change the format to "F j" and add 7 days at once?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
  date("F j", strtotime($dateEnd . "+ 7 day"));
```

Basically you need to adjust the date *before* converting it to a timestamp and then pass it to `date()` for formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$d = new DateTime( $dateEnd );
$d->modify( '+7 days' );
echo $d->format( 'F j' );
```

(PHP >= 5.2 )

Comment: Nice! And it can be done by the "Fluent Interface" style: `$d->modify('+7 day')->format('F j');`.